# При запуске бота для Discord'а выдает ошибку

Tags: python, discord, asyncio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    [![import asyncio
import sys

```
import aiohttp
import discord


bot = "токен"

SERVER_GUID = "да."

 
class LivePlayercountBot(discord.Client):
 
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Logged on as {self.user}\n" f"Started monitoring server {SERVER_GUID}")
        status = ""
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            while True:
                newstatus = await get_playercount(session)
                if newstatus != status:
                    await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(newstatus))
                    status = newstatus
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
 
 
async def get_playercount(session):
    try:
        url = f"https://aternos.org/log/{SERVER_GUID}"
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            page = await r.json()
            max_slots = page\["snapshot"\]\["maxPlayers"\]
            true_playercount = 0
            for n in range(5):
                try:
                    true_playercount += len(page\["snapshot"\]\["teamInfo"\]\[str(n)\]\["players"\])
                except KeyError:
                    pass
            return f"{true_playercount}/{max_slots}"
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting data from log: {e}")
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert sys.version_info >= (3, 7)
    assert SERVER_GUID and bot
    print("Initiating bot")
    LivePlayercountBot().run(bot)][1]][1]
```

Comment: Текст ошибки смогли прочитать, перевести и понять? )

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Конечно не профи в создании ботов для Discord,
Но с ошибки всё довольно ясно и понятно что вы в данной строке

```
LivePlayercountBot().run(bot)][1]][1]
```

Не указали аргумент `intents`

> intents (Intents) –
> he intents that you want to enable for the session.
> This is a way of disabling and >
> enabling certain gateway events from triggering and being sent.
> New in version 1.5.
> Changed in version 2.0: Parameter is now required.

Как видно в версии **2.0** данный параметр стал обязательним
Советую подробнее прочитать [тут](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

**PS:** Советую по таким мелочам не создавать вопросы, так как вы легко можете найти сами на него ответ и намного быстрее чем ждать ответ на вопрос